# Завис Sublime Text 3 при работе с внушительным php файлом при сохранении

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Собственно, вопрос, что делать? Кто виноват — понятно. Есть ли возможность спасти скрипт? Может, у Сублайма есть местечко, куда он сохраняет временные файлы? Или другие варианты? ОС — Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @Alex Lapin, посмтрите в сторону VCS (git, mercurial). У вас бы просто такой пробемы не стало при грамотном ведении проекта.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос решился. Сперва полез смотреть где бы subl мог хранить сессии. Обнаружил их в домашней папке пользователя в каталоге `/home/user/.config/sublime-text-3/local`. В файле `*.sublime_session`.

Открываю и вижу JSON массив. И, о чудо, вижу знакомый код. Правда идет он одной строкой и символы конца строки проставлены как `/n`. Отлично, скопировав, решил уйти в ребут, т.к. субл намертво завис и закрываться не хотел даже через htop. После ребута открыл subl и случилось самое величайшее во всей этой истории - последний экземпляр кода висел как несохраненная вкладка. Спасибо команде Sublime!

*Обновление*

Ах и еще вот что https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-autobackups. Замечательный антисединный плагин.

Comment: [Local History](https://github.com/vishr/local-history) ещё незаменимый плагин. Отдельно сохраняет в выбранную папку все версии файлов.