# Как в Sublime Text сделать live preview разметки Markdown?

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3, markdown

Вот есть, допустим, пакет LiveReload. Разделяешь экран на две части: в одной пишешь код, в другой сразу просматриваешь результат. Как сделать также с Markdown? Я установил пакеты MarkdownEditing и MarkdownPreview, но когда попытался разделить экран на две части, внизу появляются горизонтальные полосы прокрутки, это дико бесит. Как убрать эти полосы, чтобы можно было нормально видеть в браузере текст, который пишешь?

Comment: Несколько часов я убил на решение этой проблемы когда-то. Полчасика—час где-то подождите, распишу ответ подробно. Спасибо.

Comment: В [Atom](https://atom.io/) предпросмотр Markdown из коробки, [в соседней вкладке](http://i.imgur.com/IWNsEmh.png). Понимает даже YAML-шапку от Jekyll. Очень удобно, рекомендую. Это не помогает настроить предпросмотр в Sublime Text, поэтому публикую комментарием.

Comment: @D-side, для Atom, кстати, [**тоже есть Ghost Text**](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText-for-Atom), про который я написал в [**данном ответе**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595371/199934). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных для Atom набрал популярность [пакет Atomic Chrome](https://github.com/tuvistavie/atomic-chrome-atom), делающий примерно то же самое, но без поддержки Firefox.

Comment: @D-side, только что [**на форуме анонсировали**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/markdownlivepreview/24566/3?u=sasha_chernykh) плагин с предпросмотром, как в Atom. Однако GhostText и Pandoc по-прежнему считаю лучшими решениями. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Настроив описанными ниже действиями Sublime Text 3 на предпросмотр Markdown, я пишу в данном редакторе, например, ответы на Stack Overflow, и этот в том числе.

### Убираем горизонтальную полосу прокрутки в редактируемом файле

Устанавливаем плагин Markdown Editing → открываем любой Markdown-файл с расширением `md` или `mdown` → `Preferences` → `Settings - More` → `Syntax Specific - User`. Удаляем содержимое открывшегося файла, вместо него вставляем следующий код:

```
{
    "extensions":
    [
        "md",
        "mdown"
    ],
    "wrap_width": "0",
}
```

Т. е. мы [добавили параметр со значением](http://www.sublimetext.ru/documentation/preferences/wrap_width) `"wrap_width": "0"`. Вместо `0` я подставлял другие цифры, да хоть `4147`, всё корректно работало.

Недостаток Markdown Editing — при использовании в файлах с Markdown-разметкой плагина [LanguageTool](https://github.com/gtarawneh/languagetool-sublime), использующего обращения к API на мой взгляд лучшего спеллчекера с открытым исходным кодом [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/ru/), [не подсвечиваются все опечатки в тексте](https://github.com/gtarawneh/languagetool-sublime/issues/10).

### Убираем горизонтальную полосу прокрутки при отображении в браузере

У меня не получилось с первыми двумя плагинами, если кто-то знает, как заставить их работать так же, как Markmon, пожалуйста, сообщите в комментариях.

#### OmniMarkupPreviewer

Устанавливаем плагин OmniMarkupPreviewer. После `Ctrl+Shift+P` → `OmniMarkupPreviewer: Preview Current Markup in Browser` вместо предпросмотра может открываться страница ошибки. Чтобы её избежать: `Preferences` → `Package Settings` → `OmniMarkupPreviewer` → `Settings - User` → вставляем следующий код и сохраняем файл.

```
{
    "renderer_options-MarkdownRenderer": {
        "extensions": ["tables", "fenced_code", "codehilite"]
    }
}
```

Однако горизонтальный скроллбар остаётся.

[image: OmniMarkupPreviewer]

я спрашивал в issue tracker данного плагина на ГитХабе, как справиться с проблемой, но ответа не получил.

#### Markdown Preview

Устанавливаем плагин Markdown Preview, запускаем предпросмотр. Вместо кириллического текста в браузере, возможно, отобразятся кракозябры. Дабы их избежать, необходимо задать кодировку в редактируемом файле — `<meta charset=utf-8>`. Потребуется также установка LiveReload и включение синхронизации при сохранении файла: `Ctrl+Shift+P` → `LiveReload: Enable/Disable Plugins` → `Enable - Simple Reload`.

`Ctrl+Shift+P` → `Markdown Preview: Preview in Browser` → `markdown` (если выберем `github`, кракозябры не исчезнут):

[image: Markdown Preview]

Помимо явного указания кодировки для того, чтобы видеть результат в браузере, потребуется сохранять файл; как с этим плагином осуществить Live Preview, о котором просил уважаемый топикстартер, я не нашёл.

#### Markmon

Установка как минимум для пользователей Windows может вызвать затруднения, поэтому остановлюсь на ней поподробнее:

- Скачиваем и устанавливаем [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).
- Устанавливаем Markmon, введя в терминал команду `npm install -g markmon`.
- [Через Package Control](http://forum.sublimetext.ru/index.php?topic=6.0) устанавливаем плагин Markmon для Sublime Text 3.
- Скачиваем и устанавливаем текстовый конвертер [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/installing.html).
- Для пользователей Windows: `Preferences` → `Browse Packages...` → вручную создаём папку `sublime-text-markmon`.
- `Preferences` → `Package Settings` → `Markmon` → `Settings - User` → вставляем в открывшийся файл следующий код и сохраняем файл:

  ```
  {
  //On Windows try "markmon.cmd" if you get errors.
  //If markmon is not on your path you'll need to use a full path to it
  "executable": "markmon.cmd",
  "port": 3002,
  "pandoc_path": "",
  "command": "pandoc -t HTML5 --mathjax",
  "stylesheet": null,
  "projectdir": null
  }
  ```

`Ctrl+Shift+P` → `Markmon launch` → доступен предпросмотр в режиме реального времени. Вылезет командная строка, её не следует закрывать до тех пор, пока просмотр Markdown-разметки в браузере не будет представлять для вас необходимости, иначе придётся совершать рестарт самого Sublime Text 3.

[image: Markmon]

Answer (score 2):

Удобное решение, особенно для форм c live preview, — package [**GhostText**](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText). Подходит и для любых других разметок, не обязательно Markdown.

---

---

### 1. Демонстрация

Протестировано на:

- Windows 32-bit 10.0.14393,
- Firefox 47.0.

В браузере открыта вкладка со страницей прямо этого сайта, который вы сейчас просматриваете,  — Stack Overflow на русском. При помощи GhostText я пишу и данный ответ.

[image: GhostText]

---

---

### 2. Описание

Вы печатаете текст в Sublime Text. Точно такой же текст появляется в выбранной Вами форме на сайте, куда бы Вы вводили текст, пользуясь веб-редактором. [**Видео от разработчика**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0aLFPtYPZI&feature=share), как работает GhostText.

[**Поддерживаемые формы**](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText#website-support):

- `<textarea>`;
- [**contenteditable**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content), используется, например, в GMail;
- формы [**CodeMirror**](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText#website-support) — например, на сайтах Codepen.io, JSFiddle, JS Bin;
- формы редактора [**Ace**](https://ace.c9.io) — применяются, например, в Tumblr.

---

---

### 3. Преимущества

1. Если случайно закроете браузер, или он зависнет, либо выключат свет, а может, компьютер начнёт пищать, что его нужно будет срочно отключать и т. д. и т. п.; данные, введённые Вами в браузер, могут не сохраниться. Sublime Text же [**сохраняет данные предыдущей сессии**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/321754/199934) при рестарте. Чтобы случайно не закрыть вкладку, где печатается текст для GhostText, рекомендую использовать плагин [**Sticky**](https://github.com/avamsi/Sticky).
2. Лучше предпросматривать так, как результат будет выглядеть в конечном итоге. В Markmon/Pandoc, равно как и остальных [**рассмотренных в другом моём ответе**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/549194/199934) парсерах, свои правила оформления; на сайтах, куда Вы разместите свой текст, уже другие. Например, как будет выглядеть при предпросмотре с Markmon демонстрация из п. 1.

[image: Markmon\Pandoc]

Markmon, в отличие от Stack Overflow, не выделяет клавиши <kbd>тегом kbd</kbd> и не подсвечивает код после конструкции `<!-- language: lang-$компьютерный язык -->`. Можно произвести соответствующие настройки, но гораздо проще пользоваться GhostText.

3. Продвинутые текстовые редакторы предоставляют несоизмеримо больше возможностей для редактирования, нежели WYSIWYG.
4. Удобное деление экрана: с одной стороны — редактор, где печатается текст/код, с другой — браузер, где виден результат предпросмотра. Положим, в веб-редакторе Stack Overflow Вы заметили опечатку — придётся из места предпросмотра скроллить к форме редактирования → исправить опечатку → возвращаться к месту предпросмотра. С GhostText в перемотке нет необходимости.

---

---

### 4. Установка аддона

Начиная с 1.24.2017 пользователям [**достаточно перейти на страницу аддона**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1332194) и загрузить его, как любой другой. Перезагрузка браузера не требуется.

---

### 5. Ручная установка

#### 1. Ограничения

Метод, описанный в пп. 5.2 и 6 не будет работать для новых стабильных версий Firefox.

Начиная с релиза 48.0 в стабильной версии Firefox [**нельзя устанавливать неподписанные аддоны**](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/07/29/extension-signing-availability-of-unbranded-builds/). Несмотря на [**многочисленные возмущения пользователей**](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/07/29/extension-signing-availability-of-unbranded-builds/), как тщательно аргументированные, так и нецензурные, разработчики [**не собираются отказываться**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1332194) от нововведения. Учитывая, что проверки расширения [**приходится ждать месяц**](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText/issues/70#issuecomment-273710635), склонен согласиться с комментарием «[**как вы могли в одночасье всё так испортить?**](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText/issues/70#issuecomment-273710635)».

Тем не менее способ продолжает функционировать в Firefox

- Develeper Edition,
- Nightly,
- ESR,
- Unbranded Builds.

Поэтому не удаляю его из данного ответа. Также он может быть полезен для понимания общей картины установки аддонов в Firefox.

#### 2. Зависимости

Неплохо было бы обойтись только установкой пакета для Sublime Text и [**аддона для Firefox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/ghosttext-for-firefox/). Однако аддон не работает, а разработчик [**по всей видимости**](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText/issues/70), давно забросил проект.

Поэтому придётся собрать и поставить расширение для Firefox самостоятельно. Для этого потребуется:

- что-нибудь, чем можно клонировать репозиторий к себе. Лучше [**git**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/git.install). Также рекомендую воспользоваться [**hub**](https://hub.github.com/) — надстройкой над git, упрощающей введение его команд.
- [**Node.js**](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) вместе с npm — его пакетным менеджером;
- [**nircmd**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) для Windows, аналог для Linux — [**xdtools**](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText-for-SublimeText#installation-suggestions);
- [**XPI Compiler**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpicompiler/?src=dp-dl-othersby) — расширение для Firefox;
- сам пакет [**GhostText**](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText) для Sublime Text. После установки пакетов на всякий случай всегда перезагружайте Sublime Text.

[**Добавьте в пользовательскую или системную переменную PATH**](https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml) папки с исполняемыми файлами `git`, `hub`, `npm` и `nircmd`, если они не были туда добавлены автоматически при установке. Для упрощения работы с системными/пользовательскими переменными [**на Super User рекомендуют**](https://superuser.com/a/297950/572069) воспользоваться программой Rapid Environment Editor.

---

---

### 6. Сборка

- клонируем репозиторий GhostText; если пользуетесь Hub, введите в [**удобный для Вас терминал**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544776/199934) команду `hub clone GhostText/GhostText`;
- `cd GhostText`,
- `npm install`,
- `npm run build`.

[**Демонстрация желаемого поведения сборки на AppVeyor.**](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Kristinita/ghosttext-wlw9s)

Если сборка вышла успешной, как на демо, устанавливаем локальный аддон для Firefox. У меня не получалось скомпилировать xpi файл с помощью рекомендуемого [**консольного приложения jmp**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm), но зато удалось найти среди аддонов Mozilla кое-что получше — XPI Compiler. В адресной строке Firefox набираем `about:xpiler` → кликаем по значку папки с лупой → выбираем `$имя папки с клонированным GhostText\browser`, например, я клонировал GhostText в корень диска `E`, мой путь — `E:\GhostText\browser`. Кликаем по значку элемента паззла со стрелкой → аддон должен установиться, можно начинать им пользоваться.

[image: XPI Compiler]

---

---

### 7. Известные проблемы GhostText

- Чтобы соединиться заново, требуется закрыть все вкладки в браузере и Sublime Text, в которых использовался GhostText. Иначе могут возникать сбои.
- Иногда у меня случаются трудности в установке соединения по причинам, [**не описанным в `README.MD` репозитория плагина**](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText#close-the-connection), однако вскоре удаётся успешно установить соединение вновь. Если же не получается достаточно долго, пишите в [**issue tracker**](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText/issues) GhostText.