# Есть ли аналог xdotool для Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, поиск-программ

Необходимо автоматизировать тестирование GUI-приложений в Windows. В Linux вопрос решился использованием **xdotool**. Существуют ли его аналоги под Windows?

Comment: Тут искали — **http://alternativeto.net/software/xdotool/**? Спасибо.

Comment: Не знал про этот ресурс. Огромное Вам спасибо! Дайте пожалуйста ответ (не комментарий) на вопрос, отмечу его верным и закрою тему :)

Comment: HeroFromEarth, аналогичный ресурс, на котором можно найти альтернативы к программам — **https://suse.me/** . А здесь: **http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/** спрашивают вопросы вида `Посоветуйте софт, соответствующий $определёнными требованиям`. Перед тем, как спрашивать там, рекомендуется посмотреть, как задают вопросы другие. Спасибо.

Comment: HeroFromEarth, на [**nircmd**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) обратите внимание. Спасибо.

Comment: Ещё когда [**этот ответ**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595371/199934) писал, обнаружил, что для использования GhostText в Windows [**необходимо установить**](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText-for-SublimeText#installation-suggestions) nircmd, в Linux — xdotool. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

1. AutoHotkey https://www.saashub.com/compare-autohotkey-vs-xdotool
2. SikuliX

Больше альтернатив здесь:
https://ruprogi.ru/software/xdotool?license=free
https://alternativeto.net/software/xdotool/