# Sublime Text 3. Можно ли восстановить утерянный файл из кэша?

Tags: кэширование, sublime-text-3, хранение-данных

Писал проект в Sublime Text 3 с сохранением прямо на флешку.
Флешка загнулась, файлы потеряны, восстановить не получается.

Может быть Sublime Text 3 где-то хранит временные копии редактируемых файлов?
Хватаюсь за соломинку, ищу способ спасти работу.

Comment: Ваш кэш хранится пока вы не закроете документ, т.е. нажав на крестик.

Comment: Если кеш файл был, значит, теоретически, его можно найти и восстановить с диска С? 
   Узнать бы как он называется и где должен лежать.

Answer (score -1):

Нет, не хранит копии. Это вам не Vim.

Comment: Хранит в файле `.sublime-session`. См. [**вопрос на Super User**](https://superuser.com/q/894021/572069). Также похожий вопрос есть на [**этом сайте**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/321754/199934). Спасибо.